# How to inject a property into endpoint url call in WSO2 Integration Studio?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-data-services-server

I would like to call endpoint using a property value as parameter but it return for me this exception :

```
[2022-12-14 16:50:22,831] ERROR {DBInOnlyMessageReceiver} - Error in in-only message receiver DS Fault Message: Error in DS non result invoke.
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:filterQuery
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
```

this is my code :

```html
            <iterate expression="//accounts/account">
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <property expression="json-eval($.account.TABLE_NAME)" name="uri.var.queryString" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                        <log>
                            <property expression="get-property('uri.var.queryString')" name="nom"/>
                        </log>
                        <call>
                            <endpoint>
                                <http method="get" uri-template="http://ebs-dev:8290/services/RADMINDataService/altertable?filterQuery={uri.var.queryString}">
                                    <suspendOnFailure>
                                        <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                                        <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                                        <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                                    </suspendOnFailure>
                                    <markForSuspension>
                                        <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                                    </markForSuspension>
                                </http>
                            </endpoint>
                        </call>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
```

**Update**

this my dataservice config :

```html
  <query id="altertable" useConfig="radusage">
    <sql>ALTER TABLE :filterQuery  ADD COLUMN `numSequence` VARCHAR(20) NULL AFTER `RTCCOST`</sql>
<param name="filterQuery" sqlType="QUERY_STRING"/>
 </query>

  <resource method="GET" path="altertable">
    <call-query href="altertable">
         <with-param name="filterQuery" query-param="filterQuery"/>
  </call-query>
  </resource>
```

Comment: Based on the error it seems the exception is related to the data service and not related to the shared code here. You can try hard cording the uri.var.queryString to just to confirm whether that part is working properly.

Comment: when i invoke endpoint like this it work  --ebs-dev:8290/services/RADMINDataService/altertable?filterQuery=test

Comment: What happens when you have this? <property value="test" name="uri.var.queryString" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

Comment: it still the same error

Comment: @OussamaNairi can you share the Dataservice configs?

Comment: @ycr i have updated my question with the dataservice config .

Comment: @OussamaNairi your code seems to be fine. Probably this is related to the response payload you are getting.

Comment: @ycr the problem is not about the payload because i have already get the property value from the payload as seen in the log console .INFO {LogMediator} - {api:NumSequence} To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:80eab466-150a-44c7-b483-97da904dd9f5, correlation_id: .., Direction: request, nom = test

Comment: @OussamaNairi can you enable wirelogs and share the full log. https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/develop/using-wire-logs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are observing is due to a known issue of MI[1]. When the content type is set in the request it tries to dispatch to the data service operation based on the request body and ignores the URL params. To fix this you can either remove the `Content-Type` header as below or send a POST request with the required body to the data service. To do this, you may also need to update your data service configs.

```xml
<property name="Content-Type" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
```

Add the above property just before your call mediator.

```xml
<sequence>
    <property expression="json-eval($.account.TABLE_NAME)" name="uri.var.queryString" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <log>
        <property expression="get-property('uri.var.queryString')" name="nom"/>
    </log>
    <property name="Content-Type" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
    <call>
        <endpoint>
            <http method="get" uri-template="http://ebs-dev:8290/services/RADMINDataService/altertable?filterQuery={uri.var.queryString}">
                <suspendOnFailure>
                    <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                    <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                    <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                </suspendOnFailure>
                <markForSuspension>
                    <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                </markForSuspension>
            </http>
        </endpoint>
    </call>
</sequence>
```

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/2811